# How can I build a manual version of this?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have a class called `Package` which holds `List<string>` and `string` members, corresponding to a list of dependencies and the name of the package. It overrides `Equals()`, providing equality based on `Package` name. I am trying to build a manual version of this line:

`Uninstallable.RemoveAll(pkg => Installable.Contains(pkg));`

where `Uninstallable` and `Installable` are `List<Package>`.

My attempt at a `Contains()` method:

```cs
public static bool MyContains(this List<Package> packages, Package inPkg)
{
    foreach (Package pkg in packages)
    {
        if (pkg.Equals(inPkg))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

How can I use this extension method to build the same functionality as the above line, but without the lambda?

Comment: I'm not getting it. The method at the end is a contains method, it doesn't "build" anything. You would need to roll your own `MyRemove` that uses the `MyContains` directly.

Comment: That's what I'm asking for help with. I don't know where to start with a `MyRemove` method. I guess I didn't make that clear enough, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this foreach loop:

```
foreach ( var item in Uninstallable.ToList() )
  if ( Installable.MyContains(item ) )
    Uninstallable.Remove(item)
```

We need to call `ToList` because we modify `Uninstallable`.

Else you can use a for loop:

```
for ( int index = Uninstallable.Count - 1; index >= 0; index-- )
  if ( Installable.MyContains(Uninstallable[index]) )
    Uninstallable.RemoveAt(index);
```

Because we downcount to remove items there is no problem.

Comment: Parfait! Merci.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you can simplify your extension.

```cs
public static bool MyContains(this List<Package> packages, Package inPkg)
{
    return packages.Any(x => x.Equals(inPkg));
}
```